# ons-bottunをふたつ配置すると片方のボタンがクリックすらできない

Tags: onsen-ui

なぜこんなことが起こるのか全くわかりませんが、
表題のようにボタンがテキスト扱いのようになりクリックすらできなくなります。

```
<ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button" ng-click="myNavi.pushPage('test.html', {animation: 'slide', user: user});">もっとみる</ons-button>

<ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button" ng-click="myNavi.pushPage('test.html', {animation: 'slide', user: user});">もっとみる</ons-button>
```

上記のようにふたつ記述すると下のボタンは必ずクリックできますが、上のボタンは必ずクリックできません。（テキストの上をクリックしているような挙動）

Chromeブラウザ、デバッカー、テストビルドで実機も確認しましたが、すべてクリックできませんでした。奇妙なことにChromeブラウザでF12のコンソールを表示させながらだとクリックできるようになります。同じような挙動の例はないか探したのですが見つからず途方に暮れております。。。

何か思い当たることがあれば教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくおねがいいたします。

onsenui.js version 1.3.0

Comment: コピペして試してみましたが、普通に両方動きました。なので、おそらく質問に記載されていない部分に原因があるのではないかと思います。